# grub menu no longer is listed after switching from ubuntu to manjaro

Tags: dual-boot

so i replaced my ubuntu partition on my ssd with manjaro, and upon reboot my grub menu was gone and replaced with the grub command line interface. I noticed after digging around in bios settings that the manjaro grub was even listed in the boot sequence list. If I enter these commands:

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt4)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

it then boots to the manjaro grub menu showing all of my boot options. im honestly pretty lost since i dont have much experience in such low level stuff. my goal is to just get the manjaro grub to show when i turn on/reboot my laptop so i can choose between windows and manjaro for school. if more information is needed to help me find a solution please just let me know!

Comment: Show your laptop to a teacher or some friend knowing more Linux. If you can't, consider reinstalling Linux. BTW, why do you need Windows? Did you consider using *only* Linux?

Comment: What does `efibootmgr` return?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair